# Arriving at JFK (New York) Terminal 5 from SXM (Saint Martin)?

Tags: air-travel, new-york-city, event-based-effects, jfk, jetblue

Flying from SXM nonstop to JFK via Jetblue Saturday departing 3PM local time.  Will it arrive at JB terminal 5 or the international 4?  I ask because terminal 4 is full of protesters, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webcgi.exe?New,Kb=askBlue,case=obj(4432) "All flights (domestic, international, U.S. Territories) arrive at Terminal 5 with the exception of a few flights between 10:30 p.m. and 5 a.m. which will arrive at Terminal 4." What time is your flight?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, terminal 4 is no longer full of protesters.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was on a delayed JetBlue flight a couple of weeks ago that arrived at terminal 4 because it arrived after 10:30 pm. So it's apparently the actual arrival time that matters, not the scheduled time.

Answer (score 1):

It is also our understanding that the protests at JFK Have abated (since the courts have stayed the new immigration executive order).